# Why, Thumbnail placeholder image is not resized in catalog -> product -> edit page in Admin Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I have uploaded Placeholder image in Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Image Placeholders. but thumbnail image is not resized by default in catalog_prduct_edit page in admin Magento 2.2.5.

Page image is given below[image: catalog_product_edit page]

Comment: Have anyone found anything regarding this?